# Jquery + Css Drag and Drop offset issue

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

UPDATE: I have updated the jsfiddle to be more clear.  To clarify the issue.  When a tile is dragged from the bottom row and dropped in the top row it causes the droppable div to offset down from the other divs.  When all three divs are filled they are once again inline.  What is causing the offset of the divs when only one or two divs are filled?

I am learning jquery drag and drop now.

> The problem is that when I drop into my div it is creating an `offset`
>   in the `droppable divs`.

You can see the issue in the jsfiddle I have created, link below. I am a beginner at jquery and drag and drop so please keep that in mind if my code is butchered.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/humphrey_brent/0zcLp0La/14/)

Comment: Please explain about your issue clearly. You have two `$( ".trash" ).droppable and $( ".GridDiv" ).droppable` and I can't see your problem.

Comment: Thank you for looking at the post and the jsfiddle.  I have cleaned up the jsfiddle and added an update to clarify the question/issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it like below:

```
.componentHolder {
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left; // I used float instead of inline-block
}
```

[**Online Demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/Lrnz9eue/25/)

Comment: Thank you very much!  That is exactly what was needed.

Comment: @Brent You are welcome. Please up-vote my answer for knowing other people that it helps you because some people only see the up-voted answers.